# get the uicolor of the tapped button

Tags: iphone, button, sdk, uicolor

Hi
I have a screen which has alot of buttons with different colors. What I want is, when I press some button, I get the uiimage applied on that image and then i can get the UIcolor info or rgb value of that tapped button. I know I can use some constants to achieve that purpose but i want to do it in a dynamic and programmatic way.

More over the whole image of the button is uniform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@meronix

thanks for putting your effort in...
 I have found a similar stuff and I have used it and its working...
I wanted the RGB value to make the color so its working :)

```
- (UIColor*)getRGBAsFromImage: (UIImage*)image atX: (int)xx andY: (int)yy
{


// First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;
        CGFloat red = (rawData[byteIndex] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat blue = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat alpha = 1.0;//(rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        byteIndex += 4;

        UIColor *acolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];



    free(rawData);

    return acolor;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `(id)sender` parameter of the IBAction. This is a reference to the object that received the tap and you can use that reference to get whatever information you need.

Comment: Yes i know i can get the information of the action performer via Sender and i can get the image from that sender as well but now i hav the image and i want the rgb or color value of that image... how can i do that,,,

Answer (score 0):

Abizern is rite, i will get you with example code,

```
- (void)onTouchUpAction:(id)sender {

    //get the address of the button to your variable.
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    //change the background color.
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yourColor]];

    //remove address from the unused pointer
    button = nil;

}
```

Comment: hi jayahari, I think my question was not much clear so i edited it and hope it will be more clear. I know when i press the button i can get its each and every feature via (id)sender. What i want to do is to get the uicolor of the uiimage applied to that button or its rgb value.

Comment: @yunas: the color you are looking for is the background color of the button? or the color is in a image?

Answer (score 0):

*> i am talking about the color of the

> image and the image has a uniform
>   color... – yunas 1 hour ago*

then you may find useful those methods:

```
- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {
    UIColor* color = nil;
    CGImageRef inImage;
    inImage = self.image.CGImage;

    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
    if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 

    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage); 

    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
    if (data != NULL) {
        //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y. 
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
        int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
        int alpha =  data[offset]; 
        int red = data[offset+1]; 
        int green = data[offset+2]; 
        int blue = data[offset+3]; 
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
    }

    // When finished, release the context
    CGContextRelease(cgctx); 
    // Free image data memory for the context
    if (data) { free(data); }
    return color;
}



- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) inImage {

    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits 
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is 
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}
```

you may have to change the line:

```
inImage = self.image.CGImage;
```

with the image used in your button:

inImage = yourButton.imageView.image.CGImage;

then just call

```
getPixelColorAtLocation:aPoint // the centre of button...?
```

to get a color returned...